# touchpad 'tapping' doesn't work in login screen

Tags: kali-linux, touchpad

I am on Kali linux and while logging in if I tap on the touchpad it doesn't work. For exapmle, if I want to activate the password field, I need to hard-press my touchpad on the input field.

But after logging into the machine, the touchpad works just fine. Before logging in it doesn't respond only to soft taps. Previously I was on Manjaro linux and I faced the same issue.

I think some process here is responsible for the touchpad to be fully operational and it starts after I log in. So is there any way I can start it during boot time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an X.org configuration file to enable touch to tap:

Examples can be found at:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libinput

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

This might work for you, :

```
$ /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput.conf

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Comment: thank you a lot. worked like a charm.